# conflicts arises when inserting new row in specified index path row of UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableview with three custom(Xib) cells. I loaded each cell's in cellForRowAtIndexPath statically. Each cell contains add button to insert new row at next row. When i insert new row, it shows another Xib cell instead of expected cell and also new row adding in all sections.How to resolve it in Objective C?.
**Note:**

1) Cells loaded statically.

2) But inserting cell dynamically.

3) In numberOfRowsInSection method rows count given using an array(NSMutableArray) count.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ if (indexPath.row==0)
{
    CustomCellA *aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ACell"];
    return aCell;
} else if(indexPath.row==1)
{
    CustomCellB *bCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BCell"];
    return bCell;
}else
{
    CustomCellC *cCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CCell"];
    return cCell;
} 
}
-(void)insertNewACell:(UIButton *)addButton atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)addBtnIndexPath
{
newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[newArray addObject:@"XXXX"];
[newArray addObject:@"YYYY"];
[newArray addObject:@"YYYY"];
[sectionRowItems addObject:newArray];
[sectionRowItems insertObject:newArray atIndex:addBtnIndexPath.row];
[self.numericTable reloadData];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return alphabetArray.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all you are setting `CustomCellC` in else part. so, when you add new cell if cell `indexpath.row` is greater then 1 it use `CustomCellC`

May be you use a same array for all sections. so, when you insert new object in array `numberOfRowsInSection` will return same count for every section, there for it add new row in every section.

You can set different array for each section and also set number of rows for particular section like this:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (section == 0){
        return arr.count; 
    }else if (section == 1{
        return arr1.count;
    }

    return arr2.count;
}

-(void)insertNewACell:(UIButton *)addButton atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)addBtnIndexPath
{

    newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [newArray addObject:@"XXXX"];
   [newArray addObject:@"YYYY"];
   [newArray addObject:@"YYYY"];

   if(addBtnIndexPath.section)
    [arr addObject:newArray]
   }else if(addBtnIndexPath.section){
    [arr1 addObject:newArray]
   }else{
    [arr addObject:newArray]
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion to manage sections. Buddy how do i managed cellForRowAtIndexPath when i insert new row as i mentioned above.

Comment: You can apply conditions like numberOfRowsInSection, like i do in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, you don't need to do any changes in cellForRowAtIndexPath if you want that same cell for every section.